# What Ansible Galaxy role should I use for a simple one node MongoDB instance

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

On the Ansible Galaxy there are thousands of MongoDB roles. This makes it hard to find a suitable role for creating a simple MongoDB instance for example for Rocket.Chat.

Is there a tried and tested Ansible Galaxy role or role on GitHub that you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Generic answer - no.

This is a problem not only for MongoDB but for all Galaxy roles. I would have a look at the following points:

- how many quality scores has the role on Ansible Galaxy?
- how often it is downloaded?
- is there a good community score?
- what was the last time a change was done on the role (on Github last push)?
- has the role the options to configure my service or do I miss some settings?
- how many stars has the project on Github?
- how often was it forked or how many contributors are developing the role?
- is the role available for the latest Ansible version
- if the role uses Python - does it support Python3?
- is there a test available for it (that runs on changes in Github)
- how many issues are open and are that feature requests or bug reports?
- is the role only available for a specific environment? (you can see that, if there are yum and apt used in the install process instead of package and if there is no "switch" for both install tools)

A "good" role/project is changed often in the last days/weeks/months, there are more then one contributor or guys who forked the code. And this shows you, the developer or the community is still using it and "active". A project that is updated 4 years ago maybe gives you hints to create your own role - but you should use that. It will not have any changes.

If you cannot configure some main settings (that you know), the role isn't good and needs to be changed. You should also have a look into the source itself. Is it good structured and documented. Does it use standards? I see often roles that are terrible formated.

Use this questions and compare the roles with your needs.